# Tortoise HG mercurial 502 BadGateway

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

few days ago we have started to see this error when we tried to `hg push`.

when running `hg push --debug --traceback -v` ive got this output:

```
pushing to https://<server>/repository
using https://<server>/repository
sending capabilities command
using auth.mrsdev.* for authentication
<server> certificate matched fingerprint <fingerprint>
using auth.mrsdev.* for authentication
http auth: user trannann, password ***********
using auth.mrsdev.* for authentication
<server> certificate matched fingerprint <fingerprint>
query 1; heads
sending batch command
using auth.mrsdev.* for authentication
searching for changes
all remote heads known locally
preparing listkeys for "phases"
sending listkeys command
using auth.mrsdev.* for authentication
received listkey for "phases": 15 bytes
checking for updated bookmarks
preparing listkeys for "bookmarks"
sending listkeys command
using auth.mrsdev.* for authentication
received listkey for "bookmarks": 0 bytes
sending branchmap command
using auth.mrsdev.* for authentication
<server> certificate matched fingerprint <fingerprint>
sending branchmap command
using auth.mrsdev.* for authentication
preparing listkeys for "bookmarks"
sending listkeys command
using auth.mrsdev.* for authentication
received listkey for "bookmarks": 0 bytes
8 changesets found
list of changesets:
e34d64fb754056d112d2da58cf0675e6c9e02842
8aab72238ada787283715b6bfc0415d7fbae3709
e3583d6b2fb359db2cfb430cde7b55f38992c640
ec49b6a57c2ed999d752a4a6556bf64304bbd36f
06cef21425beb141e9f168d968124e91e8b0d364
fde87053c99bdaa171df76e7d51203e4f166c65e
59702ada4e4fba01fd166747eb043032771f7da6
3e4f6b3323d2724c2b1af6820121bcaa0c081d24
sending unbundle command
sending 21543 bytes
using auth.mrsdev.* for authentication
<server> certificate matched fingerprint <fingerprint>
**HTTP Error: 502 (Bad Gateway)**
[command returned code 255 Wed May 03 14:53:55 2017]
```

**Questions:**

1) what is happening?

2) where can I find error logs on server? Googled a while but can not find the location of logs or where is the path set.